# MATLAB C/C++ API - Update big variable

Tags: c++, api, matlab-deployment

I have just realized that if I have a variable in a MAT-file (big array) and I want to update this variable by appending a new row (suppose a 2D array) using the MATLAB C/C++ API then it is necessary to load the variable into memory, create a copy with the new row and finally overwrite the existing array with the new one.

Because I am working with big/huge arrays I would like to know how to update a variable without loading the whole thing into memory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add new data to a file at the end of it, there is no way you can "insert data in the middle of a file" (or the beginning). You need to read the file, and write the new data. If the old data is smaller than the new data, there is no way this can be done "in situ", since the new data will overwrite some of the old data.

Assuming you don't necessarily need to write it back to the original file, you could load a portion of the file at a time, and, at the beginning of processing, create a new file that you write the extended data into. Once you have written all the data, you can rename the new file to the original name of the input file, should you wish to.